# Widget update TextView timer not working

Tags: android, timer, widget, android-widget

I have a widget im trying to update the `TextView` using a timer:

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        final int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent clockIntent = new Intent(context, DeskClock.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clockIntent, 0);

        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.digitalclock);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl, pendingIntent);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                String time = "kk:mm";
                String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        }, 0, 1000);// Update textview every second

    }
}
```

Problem is, it only updates the once and never again afterwards. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a Handler, to act on the UI Thread from a timertask.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

              handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                //Your code here
             }});
        }
    }, 0, 1000);// Update textview every second
```

Also, you should initiate the Handler in onCreate() like this

> handler = new Handler();

Comment: Thanks ive got it working but it now updates for a while and then stops. Ive started a new question if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725283/widget-update-textview-timer-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
    int _count=0;
    _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
    _tv.setText( "red" );
    _t = new Timer();

    _t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _count++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 
                     _tv.setText(""+_count);
                 }
                 });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 );
```